# Flutter showing error on show/hide widget

Tags: flutter

Flutter i just need to hide my component on button pressed so i have set the boolean value and use if condition but problem is its showing error Columns children must not contain null value.

Here is my code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var first = true;
    var second = false;
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "SIGNUP",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/signup.svg",
              height: size.height * 0.35,
            ),
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Name",
              icon: Icons.person,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : null ,
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Email",
              icon: Icons.mail,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : null ,

            first ? RoundedPasswordField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : null ,

            second ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Number",
              icon: Icons.phone,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : null ,

            first ? RoundedButton(
              text: "NEXT",
              press: () {
                first = false;
                second = true;
              },
            ) : null ,
            second ? RoundedButton(
              text: "REGISTER",
              press: () {

              },
            ) : null ,
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
              login: false,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am just hiding my input widget on click and after click need to show other input and button. But getting error Columns children must not contain any null values

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SizedBox()` or an empty `Container()` instead of `null`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var first = true;
    var second = false;
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "SIGNUP",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/signup.svg",
              height: size.height * 0.35,
            ),
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Name",
              icon: Icons.person,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : SizedBox() ,
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Email",
              icon: Icons.mail,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : SizedBox() ,

            first ? RoundedPasswordField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : SizedBox() ,

            second ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Number",
              icon: Icons.phone,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : SizedBox() ,

            first ? RoundedButton(
              text: "NEXT",
              press: () {
                first = false;
                second = true;
              },
            ) : SizedBox() ,
            second ? RoundedButton(
              text: "REGISTER",
              press: () {

              },
            ) : SizedBox() ,
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
              login: false,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return Container() if the first & second variable is null
Column widget does not know how to render null
you must tell Column widget to render empty content if it's null.

Eg:

```
first ? RoundedButton(
              text: "NEXT",
              press: () {
                first = false;
                second = true;
              },
            ) : Container(),
            second ? RoundedButton(
              text: "REGISTER",
              press: () {

              },
            ) : Container(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not accepts `null` values as a Widget. You must provide at least an empty Widget if don't want to show nothing inside another widget. Usually you can use `Container(width: 0, height:0)` or even `Text('')`.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are valid, you can however use [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) to show or hide a widget, it looks like this

```
Visibility(
 visible: YOUR_BOOLEAN_VALUE,
 child: YOUR_WIDGET,
)
```